# open pdf using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

There is some pdf url which I want to open in browser. But when I tried to open it on both android and IOS, the file is not being opened. The controller is like this:

```
$window.OpenLink = function(link) {
    window.open( link, '_system');
  };
```

and the html code is like this:

```
<div  class="col col-50 clsGrid" onclick="OpenLink('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf')">
```

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

install this plugin:
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

and use this:

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('the pdf file', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
  Open pdf
                </a>
```